# Modify the `Host` header or pass `X-Forwarded-Host` instead when using Nginx as reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, asp.net, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy and the upstream server is an ASP.NET Core application where I've registered the [`ForwardedHeadersMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer), which will read three different `X-Forwarded-*` headers:

- `X-Forwarded-For`
- `X-Forwarded-Proto`
- `X-Forwarded-Host`

Now, I understand the first two, but find the last one (`X-Forwarded-Host`) confusing. I've seen Nginx reverse proxy configurations usually rewriting the `Host` header like so:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

But then I've also seen the `X-Forwarded-Host` being used instead:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

In some cases both are used at the same time:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

I'm not sure what I should do. Why would you use both at the same time? And why would anyone use the `X-Forwarded-Host` header if they can simply change the `Host` header directly? I've noticed that the result in my ASP.NET Core app will be the same regardless of whether I set `Host` or `X-Forwarded-Host` (or both), in either case, [`HttpContext.Request.Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httprequest-host) is set to the expected value — provided that the forwarded headers middleware is registered, of course.

To my surprise, I couldn't find any relevant information on this issue by googling, so I had to ask this here. What is the right approach to take in this situation?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/ "Traditionally, an HTTP reverse proxy uses non-standard headers to inform the upstream server about the user’s IP address and other request properties" is the history background on server side. `HttpContext.Request.Host` works in all cases, because Microsoft tried to keep compatibility for all typical cases. You can refer to the actual ASP.NET Core source code to learn more.